# Trying to get data on a webpage through php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This might go very basic, but I am not able to understand what is the best way to call `AJAX` on a button click event on page and get the data from the server to be displayed using php.

What I have is a simple webpage called `div.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Test
    </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                $("#data").html('Loading...');

                $.ajax({
                    url:'test.php',
                    type:'GET',
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#data").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="get">
        <button id="btn">
            Get Data from PHP file
        </button>

        <div id="data">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then a page behind it doing the database operation, `test.php`:

```
<?php 
    include ("config.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userInfo;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row["userLogin"] . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

It is pretty basic and I am supposed to get the query result on the button click, but it doesn't work. Is there something wrong in here?

Any help or ideas to understand `PHP` to `AJAX` to `JS` flow will be really appreciated.

Comment: use `json_encode` function in php file to encode the array you want to use for the data variable in JS and then use `JSON.parse(data)` in javascript. You should really stop using the old mysql functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Comment: Do you get any JS errors, PHP errors? Can you load test.php in the browser?

Comment: oh yes, `test.php` is loading in browser with the query result. But when I click the button in `div.php` nothing happens. Ideally it should pull the query result from `test.php`, but sadly it doesn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed the JS separately, you can't do what you've done but need to split as below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
           ... etc
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Separating the scripts seems to have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to debug based on the limited info available, although I think this may be the issue. Your `<button>` element is inside a `<form>` element. This means that when you click the button, it is submitting the form and reloading the page. Your AJAX may have worked but the page has reloaded so you won't see the data. Solution:

- Either remove your `<form>` from the page or look into `e.preventDefault()` for the button click function in jquery.

On another note, you should migrate your code to using another library such as PDO for accessing databases as the mysql_* functions should no longer be used.